# How to process non-square frames from camera with CoreML?

Tags: swift, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, coreml

I have trained a neural network in Keras to detect keypoints on an image. The network expects images of shape (224, 224, 3). I would like to be able to detect keypoints on images in Swift using CoreML but am unsure how to use non-square shapes with my neural network that expects square images. Any idea on proper pre-processing steps? Is there something built into the Vision API to help with this? I could just squish the images to squares but I imagine that would mess with the predicted (X,y) keypoint pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. How was the original model trained? If it was also trained on squashed images, then squashing them during inference is fine.

If not, and you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the images, you may want to set the `imageCropAndScaleOption` in your `VNCoreMLRequest` object to one of the other modes.

Regardless, you will have to convert the predicted keypoint coordinates back to whatever size you're displaying the image in. This is easiest when the image is squashed (just multiply by the width and height) but a little trickier when using one of the other `imageCropAndScaleOption`s.

Comment: Thanks, Matthijs. The network was trained on cropped images so it sounds like I will have to use the imageCropAndScaleOption. Is there any way to see the cropped image before it is processed by the model so that I can reverse engineer the scaling process in regards to my keypoints?

Comment: You can create a simple Core ML model that just outputs the input image. This lets you see the effect of different `imageCropAndScaleOption` settings and any other preprocessing options. Here is an example project that does this (from my Core ML book): https://github.com/hollance/coreml-survival-guide/tree/master/CheckInputImage

Comment: Very clever. Thank you!